# Is it better to learn English grammar separately or learn the language then the grammar follows

Tags: grammar, indian-english, learning, learning-methods

I studied grammar in my school days but I don't remember most of the rules. Still, I am able to manage somewhat. So is it necessary that we learn grammar thoroughly or just read a lot and grammar will follow?   What is the better option?
And what are the best resources/sites to learn grammar for intermediates?

Comment: If you don’t know grammar, you won’t see grammar patterns when reading.

Answer (score 1):

As an experienced fellow learner I'd suggest you learn grammar and at the same time read books and/or watch movies or series. That way you combine theory with real life usage. There is always a difference between rules and how people apply them , in any language. But I think it is good to know grammar rules, it gives structure to the learning process, but can be confusing as well. Just give yourself time. There are many free grammar sites on the internet, but you have to choose which appeal to you most. You tube also has free grammar videos. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, I never learned any grammar rules, not least because English has more exceptions than rules. 
As a learner, you may find it easier to get the basics via learning the grammar, but that will probably depend on what language you are starting from.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you learn lots of rules, those are just going to help you get along at first. In the end, you are going to learn how grammar *really* works by experience. That's because there is, basically, no consistent set of rules that straightforwardly describe English grammar. It's a mess of exceptions and contradictions. You just need to get far enough alog with it to be able to pick it up by exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are preparing for IELTS or TOEFL and take a course syllabus from a well known tutor and start to prepare.

If you just do it without any plans it will not go anywhere and you will feel too overwhelmed!

First understand the structure of a sentence and basic parts of speech. Then take things one by one and explore. And make it a habit to read some English magazines/news papers daily. During that time try to relate what you read that day.

Good luck!